# Why is $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(y_i-\bar{y})^2=\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i<j}(y_i-y_j)^2$

Tags: self-study, variance

Intuitively it seems right but does someone see how to algebraically show that
$$\sigma^2_y=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(y_i-\bar{y})^2=\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i<j}(y_i-y_j)^2$$ assuming $\bar{y}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_i$

Expanding gives:
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left[y_i^2-\frac{2}{n}y_i\sum_{j=1}^{n}y_j+(\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{j=1}^{n}y_j)^2)\right]$$ Is there an easy way to factor this?

Comment: Although *finding* such formulas for quadratic forms can be a little involved, *checking* them is easy: since both sides are obviously homogeneous, they will be equal if and only if their derivatives are equal.  The $y_k$ derivative on the left side is $$\frac{1}{n}\left(2(y_k-\bar y) + \sum_{i=1}^n 2(y_i-\bar y)\frac{1}{n}\right)=\frac{2}{n}\left(y_k - \bar y + \frac{1}{n}\sum y_i - \bar y\right)=\frac{2}{n}(y_k-\bar y)$$ while on the right side it is $$\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i\ne k} 2(y_k-y_i)=\frac{2}{n}(y_k-\bar y),$$ *QED*. Therefore no factoring is even needed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Recall that, if $\text{var}(X_i)=\sigma^2$ then
$$\mathbb{E}[(X_i-X_j)^2]=\text{var}(X_i-X_j)=2\sigma^2$$
The expansion that helps is
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i<j}(y_i-y_j)^2&=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i<j}(y_i-y_j)^2+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i>j}(y_i-y_j)^2\qquad\text{[by symmetry]}\\&=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i<j}(y_i-y_j)^2+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i>j}(y_i-y_j)^2+\underbrace{\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=j}(y_i-y_j)^2}_{\text{equal to }0}\\&=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i,j}(y_i-y_j)^2\\&=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i,j}(y_i-\bar{y}+\bar{y}-y_j)^2\\&=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i,j}\left\{(y_i-\bar{y})^2+(\bar{y}-y_j)^2+2(y_i-\bar{y})(\bar{y}-y_j)\right\}\\&=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i,j}(y_i-\bar{y})^2+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i,j}(\bar{y}-y_j)^2+\underbrace{\sum_{i,j}(y_i-\bar{y})(\bar{y}-y_j)}_{\text{equal to }0}\\&=\frac{n}{2}\sum_{i}(y_i-\bar{y})^2+\frac{n}{2}\sum_{j}(\bar{y}-y_j)^2+\overbrace{\sum_{i}(y_i-\bar{y})\sum_{j}(\bar{y}-y_j)}\\&=n\sum_{i}(y_i-\bar{y})^2
\end{align*}
Q.E.D.

Comment: That's it! Why on the last line did you not get $(n+1)\sum_{i=1}^N(y_i-\bar{y})^2$?

Comment: @user135711: check the last (double) sum on the one-before-last line, what does it give you?

Comment: @Xi'an Do you happen to know of a proof for the very first equality?